# In 10 fair coin flips, what is the probability that: (a) first two flips are the same (b) number of heads and tails are equal?

Tags: probability

a) If a coin is being flipped $10$ times, then what is the probability that the first two flips will be the same?

The sample space here would be $2^{10}$, correct?

We only need the first two flips to be the same, which means we don't care about the other $8$ flips, so would this be $2^{8}$?

So then would the probability be $\dfrac{2\cdot2^8}{2^{10}}$?

---

b) What is the probability of the amount of heads equal to the amount of tails?

I concluded this as $\dfrac{\binom{10}{5}}{2^{10}}$, because you pick the "spots" for heads, and the rest are automatically tails.

So we put divide that by $2^{10}$ and that is the probability of amount of heads equal to amount of tails.

Am I correct?

Comment: The probability of the first two coins being the same is $2 * \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}$ (because there are _two_ ways of getting the same coin for which there is a $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ chance).  It would appear that your formulation came to the correct conclusion: $\frac{2*2^8}{2^{10}} = \frac{2^9}{2^{10}} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Just as Jared said, each coin flip is an independent event so there's no need to consider the whole sample space of 10 flips, only the events of first 2 flips can be considered to calculate the probability.

Comment: @Tyler And even if it's not needed to consider the whole sample, it does not harm either, so your answer is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely right. Note that $\frac{2\cdot2^8}{2^{10}}=\frac12$. You are probably making that first one a lot more complicated than it should be, by the way. In stead, we could just note, that no matter what the first toss gives you, the second toss has probability $\frac12$ of giving the same